# Processing large arrays (65536+ elements) using C++ AMP

Tags: c++, arrays, parallel-processing, gpgpu, c++-amp

I'm having trouble processing large arrays (more than 65536 elements) in C++ AMP. I'm using C++ amp to calculate the normal, tangent and bitangent vectors for a list of polygons. The input consists of an array of positions (3 floats per position), and array of uv-coordinates (2 floats per vertex). In my parallel_for_each function, I compute the normals, tangents and bitangents (1 of each per group of 3 vertices). I write these back to arrays (encapsulated in array_view's). The algorithm looks as follows:

```
concurrency::extent<2> ePositions(positionsVector.size() / 3, 3);
concurrency::array_view<const float, 2> positions(ePositions, positionsVector);
concurrency::extent<2> eUVs(uvsVector.size() / 2, 2);
concurrency::array_view<const float, 2> UVs(eUVs, uvsVector);
concurrency::extent<2> eNormalDirections(normalDirectionsVector.size() / 3, 3);
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> normalDirections(eNormalDirections, normalDirectionsVector);
normalDirections.discard_data();
concurrency::extent<2> eTangentDirections(tangentDirectionsVector.size() / 3, 3);
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> tangentDirections(eTangentDirections, tangentDirectionsVector);
tangentDirections.discard_data();
concurrency::extent<2> eBitangentDirections(bitangentDirectionsVector.size() / 3, 3);
concurrency::array_view<float, 2> bitangentDirections(eBitangentDirections, bitangentDirectionsVector);
bitangentDirections.discard_data();

concurrency::parallel_for_each(eNormalDirections.tile<1, 3>(), [=](concurrency::tiled_index<1, 3> t_idx) restrict(amp)
{
    < ... calculate the normals, tangents and bitangents and write them back ... >
}

normalDirections.synchronize();
tangentDirections.synchronize();
bitangentDirections.synchronize();
```

The original data is contained in the *positionsVector* and the *uvsVector*. The output is stored in *normalDirectionsVector*, *tangentDirectionsVector* and *bitangentDirectionsVector*. Three positions (and associated uv-pairs) form one polygon. As only one normal, tangent and bitangent is needed per polygon, the size of the output vectors is three times smaller than the size of the input vectors. All vectors are encapsulated in array_view's in the first code block.

The algorithm works fine, as long as the number of normals to calculate is smaller than 65536. As soon as I need 65536 or more normals, I get the following exception:

> concurrency::parallel_for_each (tiling): unsupported compute domain,
>   the extent of dimension 0 of the compute domain (65536) exceeds the
>   exclusive limit (65536)

As the geometry I'd like to process consists of more than 65536 polygons, this limitation is a problem for me. I can't imagine C++ AMP is limited to the processing of less than 65536 elements. I'd therefore want to know what mistake I'm making in my approach, and how I can process arrays of more than 65536 elements.

Comment: If you are using GPGPU, the size of the arrays you can fit in GPU memory is limited, and therefore there is a hard limit on amount of data you can work on at any time. You need to divide your data into smaller blocks that can fit into the local shared memory of the threads and process those, transfer them into the global memory and get the next batch of data. This is the main bottle-neck in GPGPU.

Comment: Ah, so array_views are not stored in global memory? I had assumed that array_views were stored in global memory and that you could move the data to local memory by copying it to tile_local variables inside the parallel_for_each loop. Would a solution to my problem then be to process the array in blocks of say 50000 elements?

Comment: I couldn't find any reference for this specific error in the specs that Microsoft has [published](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/0/E/40EA02D8-23A7-4BD2-AD3A-0BFFFB640F28/CppAMPLanguageAndProgrammingModel.pdf), that is why I didn't post this as answer and just did a comment. I think if you break your data into any chunk smaller than the limit mentioned will work, or you can use a 2D or 3D extent instead where each of the dimensions are smaller than their corresponding limit so you can get more data processed at each pass.

Comment: Yeah, I also considered the 2D/ 3D extent idea. It's a great idea, but it felt like a "hack", so I assumed I was using the API incorrectly. It's also required to pad the data using the 2D extent approach, as you need to have a "rectangular block of data", which might be inconvenient. Thanks for the answer though, much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most GPUs have at least a GB of global memory, `array` and `array_view` both store data in global memory. In the case of `array_view` this is automatically synchronized with data in the host (CPU) memory. They also have `tile_static` memory which is much more limited. In this case I don't believe you are running into any memory related limits.

The compute domain is the `extent` passed to the `parallel_for_each` and describes the number of threads being used on the GPU. GPUs can only execute a limited number of total threads. This is the limit you have hit that is described in the error message. Altering the number of dimensions of the compute domain will not solve your issue, it's the total number of threads that is the issue regardless of how they are arranged. This is a general limitation of the GPU hardware (you will find similar limits with CUDA also).

You have a couple of approaches to fixing this issue.

1) You could break your calculation down into chunks that are smaller than the total thread limit. This may have the additional advantage of allowing you to hide copy overhead with the previous chunk's compute.

2) Have each thread in the compute domain calculate results for more than one polygon. This will allow you to increase the amount of work done by each thread which may improve the efficiency of the overall algorithm if it is actually constrained by the data transfers.

3) A combination of 1 & 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear explanation. I tried the solution of increasing the number of dimensions and it indeed did not work. Your approaches to fix this limitation are much appreciated as well!